# Returning list of field names in joined table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, fields-attributes, list

I need to look at all the fields in a joined table performed through arcpy. I am instigating

```
for fields in arcpy.Listfields(Feature):
  print fields
```

but it is returning a large list of:

```
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4E60>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4D40>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4B18>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4758>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4E90>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4A28>
<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0EBE4428>
```

I have done this before but forget how its done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for fields in arcpy.Listfields(Feature):
  print fields
```

try:

```
for field in arcpy.Listfields(Feature):
  print field.name
```

My changing of `fields` to `field` is not important but I think it makes the code read better.  However, what is important is that `ListFields` returns a list of field objects and so you need to examine the `name` property of each to find that out.